# How to refactor this lengthy if/else

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wrote this if/else which works fine, but it's pretty long. I'd be really interested in seeing which methods other developers would use to shorten it.

At the moment I think it looks very much like a beginner wrote it (which is correct). I'd love to see how others would approach it.

I should mention that I'm working in React Native.

```
getBatteryIcon() {
    if (this.props.batteryLevel >= 81 && this.props.batteryLevel <= 100) {
      return (
        <Image
          source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_four.png')}
        />
      )
    } else if (this.props.batteryLevel >= 51 && this.props.batteryLevel <= 80) {
      return (
        <Image
          source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_three.png')}
        />
      )
    } else if (this.props.batteryLevel >= 25 && this.props.batteryLevel <= 50) {
      return (
        <Image
          source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_two.png')}
        />
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Image
          source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_one.png')}
        />
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: FYI, I updated the answer in response to a very helpful comment from [Matt Aft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5442308/matt-aft), you might like the second option there now. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're using `if`/`else if` (well, also because you're `return`ing in each `if`'s block), you can leave off half of those conditions, because you know they won't be true:

```
if (this.props.batteryLevel >= 81) { // I assume it can't go past 100
  return (
    <Image
      source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_four.png')}
    />
  )
} else if (this.props.batteryLevel >= 51) { // Thanks to the `else`, you know it's not 81 or higher
  return (
    <Image
      source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_three.png')}
    />
  )
} else if (this.props.batteryLevel >= 25) { // You know it's not 51 or higher
  return (
    <Image
      source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_two.png')}
    />
  )
} else {
  return (
    <Image
      source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_one.png')}
    />
  )
}
```

Another option is to have a list of thresholds you loop through. Apparently, React Native doesn't let you have variables in `require` (thank you [Matt Aft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5442308/matt-aft) and [OsDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253403/osdev)), so we can't remove as much of the duplication as we might like, but:

```
const batteryLevels = [
    {level: 81, source: require("./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_four")},
    {level: 51, source: require("./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_three")},
    {level: 25, source: require("./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_two")},
    {level: 0,  source: require("./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_one")}
//          ^---- or possibly `-Infinity`, see note below
];
```

then it's

```
let {source} = batteryLevels.find(({level}) => this.props.batteryLevel >= level);
return (
  <Image
    source={source}
  />
);
```

Note that that assumes `this.props.batteryLevel` will always be `>= 0`. You could make the last one `level: -Infinity` instead of `level: 0` instead, to be ***really*** sure. :-)

---

For the general case, but this won't work for React Native because of the `require` restriction, we could factor out the path and most of the filename:

```
// NOT ON REACT NATIVE

let level;
if (this.props.batteryLevel >= 81) { // I assume it can't go past 100
  level = "four";
} else if (this.props.batteryLevel >= 51) { // You know it's not 81 or higher
  level = "three";
} else if (this.props.batteryLevel >= 25) { // You know it's not 51 or higher
  level = "two";
} else {
  level = "one";
}
return (
  <Image
    source={require(`./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/batterylevel_${level}.png`)}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let level;
var getBatteryIcon = function (batteryLevel) {
    const x = batteryLevel;
    switch (true) {
        case (x > 80):
            level = '/batterylevel_four.png';
            break;
        case (x > 50):
            level = '/batterylevel_three.png';
            break;
        case (x > 24):
            level = '/batterylevel_two.png';
            break;
        default:
            level = 'batterylevel_one.png';
            break;
    }

    return './../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable' + level;
}

console.log(getBatteryIcon(55));
```